# Pulling last value in json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file and I need to pull the last value from a particular customer id. The Json file is updated throughout the day and I have this setup to just be a function that will pull the last job number within the customer ID.

Json

```
[{"CustId":"5886708366","JobNumber":"636275400282798443c"},{"CustId":"123456798","JobNumber":"636275400535607074c"},{"CustId":"5886708366","JobNumber":"636275413000246135c"},{"CustId":"5886708366","JobNumber":"636275415626921919c"},{"CustId":"5926680270","JobNumber":"636275435491908861c"},{"CustId":"5926680270","JobNumber":"636275436824699429c"},{"CustId":"5926680270","JobNumber":"636275440818384096c"}]
```

I only need to pull from customer ID 5886708366 and use the last jobnumber in this case 636275415626921919c.

I have so far I have the following.

```
var picarioAPI = "where I pull the json file";

$.getJSON(picarioAPI, function (json) {
  for (i in json) 
    if (json[i].CustId == {{ customer.id }}) {
```

I'm stuck on getting the last part. I'm able to loop through the jobs but cant just call just that last one.  Any help would be great.

Comment: _"I have a json file and I need to pull the last value from a particular customer id."_ Do you mean the last object in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to fetch last of the requested `CustId` within your array is as follows;

```js
var json = JSON.parse('[{"CustId":"5886708366","JobNumber":"636275400282798443c"},{"CustId":"123456798","JobNumber":"636275400535607074c"},{"CustId":"5886708366","JobNumber":"636275413000246135c"},{"CustId":"5886708366","JobNumber":"636275415626921919c"},{"CustId":"5926680270","JobNumber":"636275435491908861c"},{"CustId":"5926680270","JobNumber":"636275436824699429c"},{"CustId":"5926680270","JobNumber":"636275440818384096c"}]');
var lastObj = json.reverse().find(obj => obj.CustId == "5926680270");
console.log(lastObj.JobNumber);
```

Reverse the JSON array, find the object with your `customerId`, and fetch its `jobNumber`, very straightforward one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that you will only need the last item you could get it like this:

```
var lastItem = json[json.length - 1];
```

If you know the customer ID before hand you could use the find method, which would better if the customer might not always be at the last position of the array

```
var customer = json.find(val => val.CustId === '5926680270')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through your array in reverse to get the most recent.

```
for (var i = length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  if (json[i].CustId == {{ customer.id }}) { 
  }
}
```

Comment: Elements are pushed to beginning of array, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 no they are appended to the end of an array in javascript